# Jquery auto generated clickable buttons and wrap contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello I'm wondering if it is possible to make these buttons auto generated through jquery that are clickable also. because before i made a autogenerated buttons but wont work , I mean can't click.

```
<div class="pushdown-buttons">
 <span class="toggle-indicator collapse-me"></span>
 <span class="toggle-indicator expand-me" style="display: none;"></span>
</div>
```

and also wrapped along to my autogenerated wrapper

should be inside class "pushdown-wrapper"

Please see my sample code:

http://jsfiddle.net/r95jj4oj/

it's an expanding ad. auto close after 3 secs and is responsive. (sorry for some messy codes). I'm trying to make it perfect and make it as plugin soon.

I hope someone can help me

Comment: is this what you expect http://jsfiddle.net/kishoresahas/r95jj4oj/1/

Comment: Hi that is good but that may take a lot of work because I want it user friendly. I just want only the buttons to be autogenerated and can be clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use the syntax `$(document).on('click', '.myClass', function() { // do stuff here});`

example -
change this:

```
btnCollapse.on('click', function(){
    pushdown_collapse();
    clearTimeout(frameTwo);
});
```

to this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.collapse-me', function() {
    pushdown_collapse();
    clearTimeout(frameTwo);
});
```

this takes account the new elements that are added onto the DOM dynamically